# javascript array - separate values and values of values by single quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = ["Rock Paper,Shoot,Dulce", "Once,Apple Mic,Chairs"]
```

I want to return the results like this:

```
'Rock Paper','Shoot','Dulce','Once','Apple Mic','Chairs'
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
includes = tagsI.map(tag => `'${tag}'`).join(',')
```

But this only separates by commas and single quotes the values.. not the values of the values as well.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Should the result be an array or a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the items of the array to a single string with commas. Split the string by the comma separators, map the items to the required format, and join again with commas.

```js
const array = ["Rock Paper,Shoot,Dulce", "Once,Apple Mic,Chairs"]

const result = array
  .join(',')
  .split(',')
  .map(tag => `'${tag}'`)
  .join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

split `tag` by comma and use another map

```js
var tagsI = ["Rock Paper,Shoot,Dulce", "Once,Apple Mic,Chairs"]
    
var result = tagsI.map(tag => tag.split(',').map(tag => `'${tag}'`)).join(',');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using reduce :

```js
    var array = ["Rock Paper,Shoot,Dulce", "Once,Apple Mic,Chairs"];
    
        //V1 : compatible with all browsers
    var result = array.reduce((acc, elem, index, arr)=>{
      var n_arr = elem.split(",").map(map_elem=> `'${map_elem}'`);
      n_arr.forEach(fe_elem => acc.push(fe_elem));
      return acc;
    }, []).join(",");
    
    
    console.log(result);
    document.querySelector("#res1").innerHTML = result;
    
        //V2: compatible with some browsers
    var result2 = array.reduce((acc, elem, index, arr)=>{
      var n_arr = elem.split(",").map(map_elem=>`'${map_elem}'`);
      acc.push(...n_arr);
      return acc;
    }, []).join(",");
    
    console.log(result2)
    document.querySelector("#res2").innerHTML = result2;
```

```html
<body>

  <p id="res1"></p>
  
  <p id="res2"></p>

</body>
```

The principle is the following :

- We have an initial Array "array" in which we stored strings (["Rock Paper,Shoot,Dulce", "Once,Apple Mic,Chairs"])
- For each string in the array:

  1. We split in an array the said string by ","
- We surround each element of this array by quotes
- We add each of these elements to the array that will be used as the result variable
- We created a string joining by ","

PS: If you want an array instead of a string, just remove the `join(",")`

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to split each element in the array.

```
var array = ["Rock Paper,Shoot,Dulce", "Once,Apple Mic,Chairs"];
var split = array.map(v => v.split(","));
var flattened = [].concat.apply([], split);
var str = flattened.join(",");
```